# No such file to load -- irb/error.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails 6 application running on Ruby 2.7.8, when I try to run the console `bin/rails c` I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    18: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    17: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    16: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    15: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    14: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    13: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    12: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    11: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    10: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
     9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
     8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
     7: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     6: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
     5: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
     4: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:393:in `start'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/init.rb:18:in `setup'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/init.rb:121:in `init_error'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/locale.rb:121:in `load': No such file to load -- irb/error.rb (LoadError)
```

Everything else works fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace you receive? (If not please post in its entirety) What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Thank you. Can you confirm whether or not just running `irb` is successful? If not can you run the following commands and post the result? `ruby -e "p(ENV['IRB_LANG'] || ENV['LC_MESSAGES'] || ENV['LC_ALL'] || ENV['LANG'] || 'C')"` and `ruby -e "p($:)"`.

Comment: By the strack trace it looks like you are running Ruby 2.7.0. What makes you think you are running 2.7.8?

Comment: Are you sure `irb` is installed? (Check it by running `irb`.) If it's not installed, install it first.

Comment: I cannot recreate this issue no matter how hard I try because the fallback appears to be `"irb/lc/error.rb"` no matter what locale you are in so unless you have somehow overridden `IRB::LOCALE_DIR` or broken your install in such a way that `"irb/lc/error.rb"` does not exist or is not readable, I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Can you check for a  .irbrc  file between the top level of the rails app  app and your cwd.    It may be possible that someone added some includes  for themselves that are not valid for you.    You might want to check ~/.irbrc while you're at it, just in case.

Comment: also  does  "bundle exec rails c" work for you?

Comment: @pts `bash-5.1$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.8p225 (2023-03-30 revision 1f4d455848) [x86_64-linux-musl]`

Comment: @engineersmnky `bash-5.1$ ruby -e "p(ENV['IRB_LANG'] || ENV['LC_MESSAGES'] || ENV['LC_ALL'] || ENV['LANG'] || 'C')" and ruby -e "p($:)"
"C.UTF-8"`.